# Using htmltopdf want pdf in greek language

Tags: php, html-to-pdf

I am having hard time trying to generate PDF files containing Greek letters using htmltopdf.

English letters appear in results but not the Greek ones. Searching for the problem, I think it might be related to the font used. I do not know what ttf file to use if this is the problem.I have set encoding as 'Cp1253'

Thanks in advance

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using php programming language

Comment: It would be helpful to people trying to answer your question if you show the code that is causing you an issue.

Comment: @AbhilashaShah you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you switch to [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/)! It is a little bit slower than [HTML2PDF](http://html2fpdf.sourceforge.net/), but it handles almost all Unicode languages, and has many more [features](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/enhancements) bundled with it.

> mPDF is a PHP class which generates
>   PDF files from UTF-8 encoded HTML. It
>   is based on [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) and
>   [HTML2FPDF](http://html2fpdf.sourceforge.net/), with a number of
>   enhancements.